# Mass Effect - custom character creation

Tags: mass-effect

Just starting Mass Effect.  Given how much I've read about 'John Shepard', I'm wondering if it is worth creating a custom character (which I would normally do), or if it is best to go with the standard male character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shepard is your character's name, if you don't really care about how he looks, then you don't really have to customize him at all.

Most of the story and interactions have little to do with your character origin. There are a few lines here and there that refer to your past, but nothing game changing in the grand scheme of the plot.

What does change the story are driven by the choices you make throughout the game.

Comment: thanks - I got the feel from Dragon Age that the 'correct' way to play was Human Male Noble and that the other choices felt a bit forced at places - was wondering if the same was true here, but sounds like not

Comment: @Durathor - Mass Effect's Captain Sheppard is more along the lines of DA2's Hawke; The last name is pre-picked (so it can be used in all dialog) but other than that, there's no reason not to customize to your heart's delight.